# Empty /data/log folder

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-s-2, internal-storage, insufficient-memory, logging

I have Galaxy Sii s9100 with CM 10.2 (android 4.3)

I am encountering the bug that fill the folder /data/log and display the notfication "Storage space running out"

I can see that the problem is coming from the log folder using DiskUsage (1741Mo)

The problem is I can't succeed to empty this folder, I tried :

- DiskUsage (it says that I can't delete log files)
- ES Explorer (the folder looks empty)
- Dial *#9900# (got an error IHM not valid)

Any other ideas ? Or any ideas why I can't use these methods ?

Comment: Using a terminal app (or adb shell), making yourself root (`su`), and then running `rm -rf /data/log/*` should do the trick. But instead of permanently shooing stray dogs out of your house, why not close the door? I mean, try figuring out what is filling the logs permanently, and fix that.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I'm in exactly the same situation, but I can't even use `adb shell` as my usb port is non functional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Automated solutions could involve [tasker](/questions/tagged/tasker): Make a job running in intervals (e.g. all 3 hours), with the task to shell-execute `rm -rf /data/log/*` as root, should keep the folder clean. *Tasker* has a "run shell" command, where you can tick "use root" – that's what you would need.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on i9000 and CM9. So I run **adb shell**

```
su
df
# /datadata was almost full
cd /data
ls -la
# /data/data -> /datadata
cp -rp /data/data/* /data/data2/
rm /data/data
ln -s /data/data2 /data/data
```

You may also want to have a look at "[CM7/9] /datadata/ low storage notification fix" or "CM9 datafix".