# What is `/system/app/AutomationTest_JBUP.apk`?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2

For backing up data from and repairing a stock Samsung Galaxy S2 (see [How to copy / modify data from a soft-bootlooping Samsung Galaxy S2 (GT-I9100)](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/215785/302995)), I used a recovery ROM (`PhilZ-cwm6-XWMS3-FOP-5.15.9-signed.zip`, SHA256: 406a617e8b378384bde40dd2dc6234c0660a1b4f592b6c25b3be6b6f078b9eec). This recovery ROM works without having to re-install the stock firmware (which, on this phone, is normally required). As a side-effect, it also installed the "Superuser" app, making it possible to become `root`.

After turning on the phone a few times, I was asked whether I want to allow "Automation Test" to gain super user privileges. What application is that and where does it come from? It seems like it is stored here: `/system/app/AutomationTest_JBUP.apk`.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [thread](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2417773) from Xda-developers, AutomationTest_JBUP.apk is listed among the apps that can safely be removed from a Samsung Galaxy S2. That will mean it comes installed by the manufacturer as default app.

Its package name is `com.sec.android.app.DataCreate` and [analysis of a subsequent version](https://www.hybrid-analysis.com/sample/ad439166db979ecf82acc7c088a6a700983da40be82dfb3a9997fa16b86d4fe2?environmentId=200) shows that it is from Samsung. I have no idea of its purpose.